# Excessive Planning Time for PostgreSQL Query Involving Union of 5000 Tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, union-all

I am working with a PostgreSQL database where I have a query that unions 5000 tables with identical structures. The query is saved as a view. I've noticed that the planning time for this query is significantly longer than the execution time—around 20 seconds for planning versus less than 1 second for execution.

Here's a simplified example of my query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
-- ... (up to 5000 tables)
;
```

Questions:

- Why is the planning time taking so long compared to the execution time?
- Are there any optimization techniques to reduce the planning time?
- Since the query is saved as a view, is there a way to cache or skip the planning process for subsequent runs, given that the query itself doesn't change?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Software version:

- PostgreSQL v15.4
- Docker 4.24

Comment: 5000 Tabls is execessive, you need another approach, if you have 5000 identical tables, your design needs a rethink

Comment: For the record, 50 identical tables is already excessive.

Comment: 2 identical tables is excessive *if you* ***can*** *merge them*. If you're hosting a multi-tenant database restricting each tenant to their own schema/namespace, you'd have to redesign everything with RLS instead. If those are foreign data wrappers linking remote tables, files, APIs and whatnot, complex views and functions of very different logic that are all made to only return the same set of columns, there's not much to deduplicate. I wouldn't be so quick with "the solution is you shouldn't have this problem in the first place".

Comment: A stopgap solution would be to use a materialized view, that is refreshed once an hour or so (stale data up to 60 minutes). Now, your relational design "smells" and you should revisit it.

Comment: What the comments above hint at is: forget about the schema for a minute; what is the **purpose** of these 5000 tables? Technically speaking, they could most likely be merged into 1 and the view could be dropped. However, the reason why someone went through the trouble of creating them is...? I believe knowing that could be a big step toward the right answer.

Comment: That is a horrid design, but anyway I can't reproduce the planning time being nearly that bad.  What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1. Analyzing the structure and coming up with a plan to read 5k tables takes some CPU even if they are simple and empty. The resulting plan is trivial and I suspect tables are a combination of simple, tiny and empty, so execution isn't a challenge. [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/DTSN4V2C)
2. PostgreSQL caches and considers re-using *some* query plans by default ([`plan_cache_mode=auto`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-PLAN-CACHE-MODE)). You can try to  [`PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) a select from this view, and then [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html) it multiple times, re-using some of the work put into processing the statement - *possibly* even the plan: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/XC-uZUBx). Note that this plan cache and prepared statement are owned by and exclusively available to a session, not shared, so each client would have to initially run their own `PREPARE`.

   In a test involving 5k empty tables on a PostgreSQLv15, planning repeatedly took **`10s`** for a series of repeated `select * from my_view` that unioned them all. Once I `PREPARE`d and `EXECUTE`d the statement once, its subsequent `EXECUTE`s took **`4ms`** to plan.
3. Make this view a [`materialized view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-PLAN-CACHE-MODE) to cache the result: [demo3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html). This can be shared by multiple sessions.

Remember to [`refresh materialized view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) whenever you want to discard the old cache. If you want it to automatically refresh on its own, you can set up [(statement level) triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) on the source tables that issue a [`refresh materialized view concurrently`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html#id-1.9.3.162.6) whenever there's a change to be cascaded. There's a [`pg_ivm`](https://github.com/sraoss/pg_ivm) extension that lets you make it refresh incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

You very probably missed the [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) in your desing

Example of a list partitioned table with 1001 partitions

```
create table my_table  (a int, b text, c text, d text, e text, f text, g text, h text, i text, j timestamp) PARTITION BY LIST (a);

create table my_table_0 PARTITION of  my_table FOR VALUES IN (0);
...
create table my_table_1000 PARTITION of  my_table FOR VALUES IN (1000);
```

On empty table the query is close to instant

```
explain (analyze, buffers, format text)  select * from my_table;
Append  (cost=0.00..14064.05 rows=270270 width=268) (actual time=9.176..9.460 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on my_table_0 my_table_1  (cost=0.00..12.70 rows=270 width=268) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
...

Planning Time: 24.782 ms
Execution Time: 13.456 ms
```

The your desing with 1001 tables with *union* view leads in the same empty setup to

```
Planning Time: 1290.083 ms
Execution Time: 16.412 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem was fixed in v16, with [commit e42e312430279d: Avoid O(N^2) cost when pulling up lots of UNION ALL subqueries](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e42e312430279d) (which is not mentioned in the release notes).

Before that commit, I get OOM errors.  But if I had enough memory not to get errors, I assume it would be slow.